# The cyclic nature of group U(n)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

For what possible values of n is U(n) cyclic?Is there any general result regarding this?If yes please could anyone state it and possibly give me a hint about its proof.

Comment: What is your definition of $U(n)$? Usually it denotes the unitary group, but I suppose this is not the case here. Please add your own thoughts/efforts on the problem so that we could have some clue of how to help you.

Comment: By $U(n)$, do you mean $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$?

Comment: For $m\ge3$, $(\mathbb Z/2^m\mathbb Z)^\times$ is not cyclic, because $\pm1$ and $2^{m-1}\pm1$ are four distinct elements of order $2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  slight correction.  $(\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z)^\times\cong \Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$, so only has three elements of order $2$.

Comment: You are correct, @ChrisCuster; I suppose I meant of order $1$ or $2$

Comment: As we know, a cyclic group has at most one element of order $2$.

Comment: U(n) is the set which consists of all natural numbers which are less than n and relatively prime to n.Thus the group is  U(n) along with multiplication Modulo n

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention it clearly.I thought it was a well known notation just like Zn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group is cyclic if and only if $n=1,2,4,p^k$ or $2p^k$ where $p$ is an odd prime.

Gauss knew this.  It seems to me the result is fairly nontrivial, requiring the proof that there is a primitive element mod $n$ in those, and only those, cases.  If memory serves this problem was at least partially considered in his *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae* of $1801$.